# Object does not support this property or method IE8 error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am running one application which is loading properly in all browsers except and keep getting "Object does not support this property or method" error. I am not sure which part to share here as i myself don't know which part is generating the error. Can anybody help me out with the area to look out for .

Comment: If it works in all browsers but ie then it must not be supported by that version of ie what method are you calling on what object?

Comment: i am using lots of javascript, you can see but i am also not sure which part is causing the issue while loading.

Comment: Your link is not working...

Comment: Can u try again please.

Comment: IE8 doesn't use `addEventListener`. It uses `attachEvent`. See also `detachEvent`.

Comment: There's a cross-browser solution: http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent

Comment: You can put IE8 in debug mode and re-run your site. It will point to the exact line where the error is being thrown.